# JPA/Hibernate join on embedded columns

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables represented by following classes

```
@Entity
public class Document {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @NaturalId
    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "object_id"))
    @AttributeOverride(name = "type", column = @Column(name = "object_type"))
    private ObjectRef object;
}

@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @NaturalId
    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "object_id"))
    @AttributeOverride(name = "type", column = @Column(name = "object_type"))
    private ObjectRef object;
}
```

The `ObjectRef` is `Embeddable`

```
@Embeddable
public class ObjectRef {
    private String id;
    private String type;
}
```

The data model already exists in larger context and can't be changed.

The `ObjectRef` can be used to connect Person and Document, right now we have method in PersonRepository `findByObject` and it is used to fetch related Person for given document.
But this is quite inefficient when we have large collection of Documents so I wanted to get all data in single query.
Something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM document d
JOIN person p on p.object_id = d.object_id and p.object_type = d.object_type
```

So I extended the `Document` entity with

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "object_id", referencedColumnName = "object_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "object_type", referencedColumnName = "object_type")
    private Person person;
```

But that does not work, the application won't even start

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(object_id, object_type) of com.icerik.test.model.Document.person referencing com.icerik.test.model.Person not mapped to a single property
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1694)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1623)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    ... 86 more
```

When debugging I have found that both `object_id` and `object_type` have `org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getColumnSpan() == 2` which then causes them to be ignored and hibernate throws that exception.

How should I model this relation in hibernate / jpa to get my desired query?

Repo with "working" code https://github.com/RobertOzga87/jpa_join_embedded

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this but have you tried to use `@JoinColumns` which accepts `@JoinColumn` array? As an example here: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JPA/0910__JPA_ManyToOne_Two_Join_Columns.htm

Comment: The `@JoinColumns` works the same way as multiple `@JoinColumn` and there is no difference in exception message.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to an existing hibernate issue related to using composite natural ids to map entities.

PLEASE SEE: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12930